# Как прочитать текстовый файл с числами?

Tags: c, массивы

Мне необходимо прочитать текстовый файл в двумерный в котором 1 строка - количество строчек массива, 2 строка количество столбиков. Дальше записан сам массив, вот пример входного текстового файла:

```
4  
7  
11 6 11 6 3 10 6  
7 9 6 13 5 15 5  
1 10 12 7 13 7 5  
13 11 10 8 10 12 13
```

Вот что я писала:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    FILE *fp;
    const int N = 150;
    char A[N][N], s[N];
    int i, j, stroki, stolbci;
    fp=fopen("test.txt", "r+");
    if(fp == NULL) 
    { 
        printf("Oshibka otkritiya.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &stroki);
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &stolbci);
    for (i=0; i<stroki; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<stolbci; j++)
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%s", s);
            (A[i][j])=s;
        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<stroki; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<stolbci; j++)
        {
            printf("%i", A[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Выдает ошибку

> error C2440: =: невозможно преобразовать 'char [150]' в 'char'

Помогите, как записать такие числа в массив? 
текстовый файл может быть максимум 50*50 любых цифр, но с описанной выше структурой.

Comment: Спасибо, mikillskegg, у меня все получилось!!)))

Comment: Тогда вопрос принимаем и ставим плюсик

Comment: Ясно с массивом. Сейчас попробую исправить, спасибо)  Какой плюсик?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Массив А сделать типа int. Считывать данные прямо туда так

```
 fscanf (fp, "%d", &A[i][j]);
```

Массив s выбросить за ненадобностью.

Массив А лучше выделять динамически, примерно так

```
int* A = (int*) malloc (stolbzy*stroki*sizeof(int));
for (i = 0; i < stolbzy*stroki; i++) 
   fscanf (fp, "%d", A+i);

for (i = 0; i < stolbzy*stroki; ) {
  printf ("%i ", A[i]);
  if ( (++i) % stroki  == 0) printf ("\n");
}
free (A);
```